# Any possible methods to make the X86WebCam button work on Linux, just like on Windows, to enable/disable camera?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-event

I am using a laptop with a camera switch in the keyboard, triggered by <kbd>Fn</kbd>. In most cases, since I am using dual boot with Windows 11, the camera is disabled using it. A red LED on the keyboard is on to show the *disabled* status, and when I enable it, the LED is off.

On Linux, however, I cannot disable the camera using the button. However, the LED is always on while the camera is available, unless I turn the camera on to make the LED off inside Windows, and then shutdown and boot Linux.

I have checked by `xev`, which recognized the key as `keycode 220 (keysym 0x1008ff8f, XF86WebCam)`.

My WM is hyprland, which enables me to bind a command (even starting with `sudo`) to a single key. The button beside it (`XF86AudioMicMute`), which is used to control microphone, works fine when binded to `pactl set-source-mute @DEFAULT_SOURCE@ toggle`. The LED is on when the microphone is disabled(muted), and off when microphone enabled. I searched GitHub and found nothing about how `X86WebCam` is configured. Thus I am asking for the possibility of making it work.